# Protect website from non-authenticated users

Tags: django, django-views

When user is not logged in, he should be redirected to the login page.

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated()
    # redirect to the login page
```

But this code must be written in each view. There is a way to write common code for all views only one time?

Comment: Could you make your authorization checks at the server level using something like .htaccess ?

Comment: No, it's should be done using django

Comment: You should take a look at the Django book.  There's a [free online version](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/) if you don't want a physical copy.  It has a nice section on [sessions, users and registration](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter12/) which mentions the neat decorator mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with a piece of middleware:

```
class RequireLoginMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
        return None
```

Of course, you don't want to do that for the login page itself:

```
class RequireLoginMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith('/login'):
            return None
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
        return None
```

Answer (score 8):

How about the `@login_required` decorator? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: Obligatory reference to the [note on the `@login_required` decorator in the Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter12/#cn137).